# How to refresh layout after set translation Y

Tags: android

I created recyclerview and header layout, when I scroll up recyclerview, the header layout should be disappeared according to the scrolling offset of recyclerview.

My layout xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:id="@+id/header"
              android:text="Mao Minh Tri"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the implemented code when scrolling recyclerview

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (originalHeight == 0) {
                originalHeight = myrecyclerView.getHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = myrecyclerView.getLayoutParams();

            calculateLocationAndProductStickerOffset();
            textview.setTranslationY(-offset);
            mainView.setTranslationY(-offset);

            if ((offset < textview.getHeight() && dy > 0) || (offset > 0 && dy < 0)) {
                offset += dy;
            }


            System.out.println("original height --> " + originalHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

        }
    };

    myrecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
}

private void calculateLocationAndProductStickerOffset() {
    if (offset > textview.getHeight()) {
        offset = textview.getHeight();
    } else if (offset < 0) {
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```

And my result:
[image: before scrolling]
[image: after scrolled]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://robusttechhouse.com/tutorial-how-to-add-header-to-recyclerview-in-android/) the best way to use a header with recycleview without using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to do all of that.. you just need to change your parent layout from RelativeLayout to CoordinatorLayout which supports doing that by default.

Here's a good tutorial to do that:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout